# hapi.js subdomain using switch

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Is this the right way to make hapi.js server with subdomain?
Are there any cons?

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/{path*}',
  handler: (request, reply) => {
    switch (request.info.host) {
      case 'api.domain.sk':
        return reply('api.domain.sk')
      default:
        switch (request.path) {
          case '/css/file.css':
            return reply.file('./public/css/file.css')
          case '/js/file.js':
            return reply.file('./public/js/file.js')
          default:
            return reply.file('./public/index.html')
        }
    }
  }
})
```